# Adding androidx espresso-contrib to androidTestImplementation creates dependancy / constraint errors

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

After adding `androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0` dependency I'm trying to test my UI and the build is failed for dependancy / constraint errors. I haven't found any solution in online for androidx `espresso-contrib`. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

The error log is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'espresso-contrib.aar (androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: C:\Users\Almas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.test.espresso\espresso-contrib\3.2.0\55de2d3fd0f8286c18c3a30c445033f20cc314be\espresso-contrib-3.2.0.aar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                                   
   > Failed to transform artifact 'accessibility-test-framework.jar (com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:2.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Almas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework\accessibility-test-framework\2.0\7837f95bdff9f797003454247fef02b78d49ae75\accessibility-test-framework-2.0.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                                                  
   > Failed to transform artifact 'material.aar (com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: C:\Users\Almas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.android.material\material\1.0.0\f83e012c22d2fac8fcf23880d7167832b099fa94\material-1.0.0.aar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                           
   > Failed to transform artifact 'transition.aar (androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: C:\Users\Almas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.transition\transition\1.0.0\f3556ce8f251984acb24014c3ba055ff235929ff\transition-1.0.0.aar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:
```

The app build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testinginandroid"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'

    // Automation framework for Unit as well as UI testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    // Espresso core dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // Espresso contrib for DatePicker, RecyclerView, Drawer actions, Accessibility checks, CountingIdlingResource
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
    // Mocks (fakes) dependencies required by the class being tested
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Comment: please add the error log